# JavaScript need a way to clean up JSON.Stringify without modifying a helper function

Tags: javascript, json, filter, higher-order-functions

Working on an assignment. I am using .filter() to find a list of active members. Following the instructions of the assignment the output is very messy. I would like to only display the member names or the member _ids.

This is the helper function and I cannot modify this function. As a rule of the assignment.

```
const printKata = function (kataNumber, object) {
    const detailsElement = document.createElement("details");
    main.append(detailsElement);

    const summaryElement = document.createElement("summary");
    summaryElement.append("KATA " + kataNumber);
    detailsElement.append(summaryElement);

    const stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify(object);
    detailsElement.append(stringifiedObject);
```

...

Here is an example of the user object

```
const users = [
  {
    _id: "5efb83d333dadb00fc5f68e4",
    isActive: true,
    balance: "$2,967.17",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 21,
    eyeColor: "green",
    name: "Gregory Villarreal",
    company: "BLUPLANET",
    email: "undefined.undefined@bluplanet.name",
    phone: "+1 (866) 544-2326",
    registered: "Friday, May 24, 2019 3:08 PM",
    tags: ["quis", "irure", "consequat", "ut", "occaecat"],
  }
```

...

And here is the simple function to filter the data.

```
let userActive = users.filter(function (user) {
    return user.isActive === true;
});
```

...

Currently it is displaying all the data from the entire object. I think it would look a lot nicer to only display the name and or id ..

I am very new to all of this. Please be patient with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently it is displaying ***all the data from the entire object***. I
> think it would look a lot nicer to ***only display the name and or id*** ..

To do that, Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) just after your `filter` method, to specify only fields you want from objects and not all of them.

```js
const users = [{
      _id: "5efb83d333dadb00fc5f68e4",
      isActive: true,
      balance: "$2,967.17",
      picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
      age: 21,
      eyeColor: "green",
      name: "Gregory Villarreal",
      company: "BLUPLANET",
      email: "undefined.undefined@bluplanet.name",
      phone: "+1 (866) 544-2326",
      registered: "Friday, May 24, 2019 3:08 PM",
      tags: ["quis", "irure", "consequat", "ut", "occaecat"],
    }]

    let userActive = users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.isActive === true;
    }).map(({id,name})=>({id,name}));
    console.log(userActive)
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. It is outside the scope of the assignment. But I couldn't stand looking at it like that.

Comment: Glad it helped! it is called `Destructuring assignment` you can read more about it [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: When I try to use this method later in the assignment. I am getting an error that .map is not a function.. 

It looks like this.
...
let sortUser = users
 .find(function (user) {
  return user.age >= 28;
 }).map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }));

printKata(4, sortUser);

...

Answer (score 0):

This function is returning what you are asking from it:

```
let userActive = users.filter(function (user) {
    return user.isActive === true;
});
```

"Filter the users array and return the user where isActive is true."

The return is the user object (or users if there is more than one) with all the key/value pairs.

As suggested in the previous answer, you can chain the map method at the end and return the values you want.